# jQuery .append() function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing an error (Oops, try again. Make sure to use `.append()` to add your item to your). when I tried with `$('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>')..append('.list');` Its working fine but I couldn`t find a solution or reason why .append() function talking two periods instead of one. It would be a big help for me if anyone can give me a solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
       var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
       $('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>').append('.list')

   });
 
});
```

```css
h2 {
    font-family:arial;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
}

#button{
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
 width:70px;
 background-color:#cc0000;
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:2px;
}

.list {
 font-family:garamond;
 color:#cc0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>To Do</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>To Do</h2>
  <form name="checkListForm">
   <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
  </form>
  <div id="button">Add!</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="list"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `appendTo`?

Comment: No i mean`t append(). For example

So I append my order with another burger:

myOrder.append(another burger).

Or, I might say: I'd like to take a burger and append it to my order:

burger.appendTo(myOrder).

take this new thing and appendTo an already existing thing
vs
take already existing thing and append this new thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){

       var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
   
       $('div.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>')

   });
 
});
```

```css
h2 {
    font-family:arial;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
}

#button{
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
 width:70px;
 background-color:#cc0000;
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:2px;
}

.list {
 font-family:garamond;
 color:#cc0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>To Do</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>To Do</h2>
  <form name="checkListForm">
   <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
  </form>
  <div id="button">Add!</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="list"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## **Like this?**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
       var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
       $('<div />',{html:toAdd,class:"item"}).appendTo('.list')

   });
 
});
```

```css
h2 {
    font-family:arial;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
}

#button{
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
 width:70px;
 background-color:#cc0000;
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:2px;
}

.list {
 font-family:garamond;
 color:#cc0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>To Do</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>To Do</h2>
  <form name="checkListForm">
   <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
  </form>
  <div id="button">Add!</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="list"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```